# Changing SQL Server 2000 usernames

Tags: sql-server-2000, users

We're running a SQL Server 2000 instance with users tied to Windows accounts. Many of the usernames have spaces in them and that is causing us some problems now. We would like to be able to rename them to get the spaces out, but I'm unable to figure out how this is done. I would love some help on this.

Comment: Would an answer to workaround spaces help? And do the AD accounts have spaces in?

Comment: They do, yes. Mine for example is DOMAIN\Andy Soell
A workaround is fine as long as my linked Access application won't complain when it tries to create views. If I try to create a view, it tries to name it "Andy Soell.viewname" and that space is causing me problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes

- When you create a login, then the name must match AD exactly
  `EXEC sp_grantlogin 'DOMAIN\Andy Soell`
- When you map the login to a database user, it can be renamed
  `EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'DOMAIN\Andy Soell', 'Dilbert'`

The 2nd bit will fix your issue with implied schema. This happens if don't qualify schema (eg dbo) because SQL Server 2000 has pretty much no [user-schema separation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387%28SQL.90%29.aspx) like later versions

Note: you can't rename users in SQL Server 2000 IIRC: need to run sp_revokedbaccess then sp_grantdbaccess. If you own objects because of your implied schema then you'll need sp_changeobjectowner. I think SQL EM will prompt you.

That is, you should *always* qualify schema in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.viewname...

SELECT * FROM dbo.myTable

EXEC dbo.MyProc
```

Then no need to change the users

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much! I know that it would be preferable to save view as dbo.viewname, however it seems that Access will still try to save new views on a linked SQL Server with the user's name, even if they are flagged as a database owner. Hence my problem htere.